Creating DaisyUI drawer relative to a container div
I have a simple app whose body is 500px wide and centered.
I am trying to use daisyUI drawer so that the drawer enters the screen just at the right of the body.
However, the drawer opens from the far end of the viewport instead of right adjacent to the screen.
I tried a number of approaches but none worked.
Below is the code.
<body>
    <h2>My App</h2>
    <div class="drawer drawer-end">
        <input id="my-drawer-4" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />
        <div class="drawer-content">
            <!-- Page content here -->
            <label for="my-drawer-4" class="drawer-button btn btn-primary"
                >Open drawer</label
            >
        </div>
        <div class="drawer-side">
            <label for="my-drawer-4" aria-label="close sidebar" class="drawer-overlay"
            ></label>
            <ul class="menu bg-base-200 text-base-content min-h-full w-80 p-4">
                <!-- Sidebar content here -->
                <li><a>Sidebar Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>Sidebar Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
:global(body) {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-family:  sans-serif;
}


I was able to get the result you're looking for by utilizing CSS variables. In your Tailwind CSS file, add the following:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* You can change the default behavior of the scroll bar
 * appearing/disappearing by changing `scrollbar-gutter` 
 * to "unset" or "stable".
 */
html:has(.drawer-toggle:checked) {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  scrollbar-gutter: unset;
}

body {
  --max-width: 500px;
  max-width: var(--max-width);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.drawer-side {
  max-width: var(--max-width);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

I tried solving this another way by changing the side drawer to position: absolute so that it can be positioned relative to a parent element, but I decided it wasn't a good solution because it would likely break when nesting the drawers.
Here is a working example.

I will try this out and update. Thank you for answering!
